# Can't build project in Android Studio console

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I try integrate gradle 2.0.0 plugin into my project. When i try build project by AS everything is fine. But when i try build project through console
(`./gradlew build` or `./gradlew assemble` (before i call `./gradlew clean`)) i get most popular build exception in last time

```
 com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry
```

Now i have last build tools.How it possible? Whats wrong?

Comment: You have a duplicate dependency. Show the full error and your gradle file.

Comment: Then why project builds fine through run button in Android Studio ?

Comment: and you usually have two gradle files...  usually we want to see the module app one (http://installingcats.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/android-studio-build-gradle.png)